# Consider the general equation of a circle in $(x,y)$-plane and use the transformation $w = \frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the general equation of a circle in $(x,y)$-plane and use the transformation $w = \frac{1}{z}$ where $w = u + iv$ and $z=x+iy$.

I understand that

\begin{align}
u = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\\
v = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\\
|w|^2= \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\\
\end{align}

but i don't understand how the equation transforms to

\begin{align}
a+bu-cv+d(u^2+v^2)=0
\end{align}

could someone please xplain this to me?

Comment: You omitted to state the equation of the circle for $x,y$ that begins the calculation.

Comment: The equation was not given in the question. I am guessing we had to use our own.

Comment: If you can just show me how to get to any equation of that form that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** See also wiki on [generalised circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle#The_transformation_w_.3D_1.2Fz). Basically, as shown in the wiki:
$$
A z \bar z + B z + C \bar z + D  = 0$$ goes to

$$D \bar w w + C w + B \bar w + A = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Call the given circle
$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2\ .$$
Note that
$$x+iy=z=\frac{1}{w}=\frac{1}{u+iv}\ .$$
Now you can find $x,y$ in terms of $u,v$, substitute into the equation of the circle, and simplify.

Good luck!